# Show a Call Screen/Wake up device after receiving FCM onMessageReceived() (WITHOUT tapping on notification)

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I am making an app using OpenTok and FCM. Right now, I am able to successfully receive push notifications in onMessageReceived and handle those data however I want to.

My question is, I want to show a "Calling Screen" (as in the screen you get when someone is calling you) whenever I receive a push notification. Can someone point me to the right direction? I assume I need to use a BroadcastReceiver but in conjunction with what? Wakeful services?

My biggest problem right now is how do I show the calling screen when the phone is locked or when my application is killed or in the background.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You will need to acquire `WakeLock` . Look out for documentation.

Comment: @ADM okay Ill take note of that. However, how can I invoke an activity (call screen) in onMessageReceived() ?

Comment: Just start it as usual .. with the flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` . You can add more flags as perthe need

Comment: @ADM ohh. I didn't realize I could start an activity from the receiver. I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: but how if the apps is swipe off or killed? it can't receive any more...